# How to make UIAlertController's message selectable

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

How to make UIAlertController's message selectable with a long press gesture recognizer?

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

`UIAlertController` doesn't provide text selection functionality. If you want to do copy this then you could alternatively provide a button on your UIAlertController that copies a string to the pasteboard.

OR

Add a `UITextField` to `UIAlertController`, by this you can select the text in `UITextField`, to stop editing in it, implement `delegate` method for `UITextField`.